# Tensorboard - moduleNotFound: no module named tensorflow.tensorboard

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have got Tensorflow 1.3.0 saved in this path:
C:\Users............\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-1.3.1

and in this folder i had install tensorboard by conda.

When I launch

```
tensorboard --logdir=/tensorflow-1.3.1/tensorflow/contrib/tensorboard
```

Give me an error: moduleNotFound: no module named tensorflow.tensorboard

Which is the problem?

Comment: Is it possible to use tensorboard in windows instead of linux?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't launch the actual tensorboard, but rather you want tensorboard to read the logs that you have created during you session.

So somewhere in your script you created a path, for example

```
logs_path = "./tmp/"
```

where the logs from the training are saved through the writer ran in your session:

```
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(logs_path, graph=tf.get_default_graph())
```

Then to visualise the values from the logs, you launch tensorflow and give it the path to the logs.

```
 tensorboard --logdir=./tmp --port 6006
```

You can then open your browser with the specified port where the outcome should be.

Comment: The problem persists.
Use tf.summary.FileWriter or tf.train.SummaryWriter is the same correct?

Comment: are you writing any variable with the writer??

What is the exact error now?

Comment: The error is the same! moduleNotFound: no module named tensorboard.

Comment: In my tensorboard field i don't have tensorboard.py It's possible that the error is due to this?

Comment: Is it possible to use tensorboard in windows instead of linux?

Comment: Yes. The setup is more or less the same as on linux. Google will offer you plenty tutorials.